Typescript complaining value can be undefined despite type not being undefined
I have this typescript code:
type ApiMethods = {
  getToken(args: { tokenAddress: string; tokenName: string }): string;
  getRank(): string;
  getName(): string;
};

type Payload<K extends keyof ApiMethods> = Parameters<
  ApiMethods[K]
>[0] extends undefined
  ? {}
  : Parameters<ApiMethods[K]>[0];

function buildUrl<M extends keyof ApiMethods>(
  payload: Payload<M>,
) {
  let keys = Object.keys(payload)
}

Object.keys(payload) in the last function gives the following error:
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(o: {}): string[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{} | { tokenAddress: `0x${string}`; tokenName: string; } | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '{}'.

I don't understand in what case Payload can be undefined since it is set to Parameters<ApiMethods[K]>[0] only when it isn't undefined, and when it is, it is set to an empty object {}.
I know I can fix it by doing Object.keys(payload!), but I was wondering why the type isn't explicitly telling TS that it can't be undefined.

I've edited so that the non-[mre] isn't even in the question, where it would still serve as a distraction. Interested parties can always view the edit history. Is that okay with you, I hope?

The answer here is in ms/TS#35257; TS isn't a proof solver and cannot accurately draw conclusions from arbitrary generic type functions, especially those using conditional types. Payload<M> where M is generic is mostly opaque to the compiler. If you want TS to know what Payload<M> cannot possibly be undefined (or null) then you can intersect it with {} as shown here. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Yes it is ok with me and it addresses my question. Thanks.

TypeScript lacks the higher-order reasoning ability to derive invariants from generic types by itself. This is especially bad for conditional types, which in principle can have all sorts of crazy behavior. The compiler cannot say: "hmm, no matter what K is, Payload<K> will be non-nullish". In order to do that it would have to either iterate through every possible type that K could be and check each one (which is intractable to implement, see this Twitter tread on incompleteness by the TS team dev lead), or somehow be able to keep track of every logical consequence of the structure of Payload (which would also be intractable).  The only higher-order conclusions TypeScript can draw about generic types are the ones it is explicitly implemented to look for.  Otherwise it will essentially give up, and prevent you from making assignments even if they turn out to be safe. See microsoft/TypeScript#35257 for more information.
There will always be situations where you know (or at least believe) that a type X is assignable to a type Y but the compiler doesn't agree, because either X or Y depend on some generic thing the compiler can't analyze.  In such situations, you can often work around the issue by using the intersection X & Y in place of X.  One of the rules the compiler does know is that X & Y is always assignable to both X and Y.  And if you're correct that X is assignable to Y, then the type X & Y should be equivalent to X (because if every value of type X is assignable to Y, then X & Y should include all of X. It turns out to be a bit more subtle than this, and there are alternatives like Extract<Y, X> or Extract<X, Y> depending on the use case, but I won't digress further here).
Since Object.keys() wants its argument to be non-nullish (e.g., assignable to {}), then you can redefine Payload<K> to be
type Payload<K extends keyof ApiMethods> = (
  Parameters<ApiMethods[K]>[0] extends undefined ? {} : Parameters<ApiMethods[K]>[0]
) & {};

and then it will just work:
type X = Payload<"getName">; // type X = {}
type Y = Payload<"getToken">; // type Y = { tokenAddress: EthereumAddress; tokenName: string; }
 
function buildUrl<M extends keyof ApiMethods>(
  payload: Payload<M>,
) {
  let keys = Object.keys(payload) // okay
}

Playground link to code
